# Streamline Plot from velocity discrete values

Tags: plotting, visualization

I solved Navier Stokes equation in C for lid driven cavity flow and extracted converged values of `u` velocity and `v` velocities in `.dat` file.

Is there a way to generate streamlines from these discrete values of `u` and `v` in *Mathematica*?

[u.dat & v.dat](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2zqILhKX1cLfjdXd1o0MzNRVERqT3VkVEloanRUaUV0ZlRBTUp0aVU0MFR0Mk9FcmhFUWM&usp=sharing)

I have attached link for `u.dat` and `v.dat` files, but even if someone can guide me with his own data set, I will be thankful.

Comment: And what is the `u` and `v`? Have you looked in the [`ListStreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStreamPlot.html) documentation?

Comment: @m0nhawk : Hi, I looked in the documentation of ListStreamPlot but was not able to figure out my problem.

u is the x direction velocity and v is the y component of velocity. 

I solved NS equations using FDM methods on a grid size of 401X401, so basically u and v represents velocity values at these grid points. 
u and v are  401X401 matrix

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The main thing with the [`ListStreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStreamPlot.html) is that it needs a data in a form of list of `{{x, y}, {vx, vy}}` pairs.

```
vx = Import["Re1000_c100_u.dat", "CSV"];
vy = Import["Re1000_c100_v.dat", "CSV"];

x = Table[j, {i, 0, Length[vx] - 1}, {j, 0, Length[vy] - 1}];
y = Table[i, {i, 0, Length[vx] - 1}, {j, 0, Length[vy] - 1}];

ListStreamPlot@MapThread[{{#1, #2}, {#3, #4}} &, {x, y, vx, vy}, 2]
```

I'm not sure if the [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) is the most efficient way to create a necessary list.

Comment: `Transpose[{{x, y}, {vx, vy}}, {3, 4, 1, 2}]` is another way to arrange the data for `ListStreamPlot`. (+1)